# Icons I'm using from "@material-ui/icons" do not respond to my SCSS code

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, display

I have imported some Icons from "@material-ui/icons". They appear on the screen correctly, however when I try to manipulate them with SCSS, they do not respond.

I have *Display: none;* however both icons remain on the page.

I have an Index.css file as-well, however I don't believe that should be overwriting this tag.

I tried adding other CSS to the tags for the icons, however they don't move or change.

```js
import  React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles/Header.scss"
import { Close, MenuBookOutlined } from "@material-ui/icons";
import {A} from 'hookrouter'; 


const Header = () => {

     const [active, setActive] = useState(false);

     const showMenu =() =>{
        setActive(!active)
     }

    return(
    <div className="header">

        <div className="header_logo">
            <h1>Christian Bryant</h1>
        </div>

        <nav className="navbar">
            <ul>
        <div className= "closed">
            <Close className = 'close' onclick ={showMenu}/>
        </div>
            <li>
            <A className='Link' href='/'>HOME</A> 
            </li>
            <li>
            <A className='Link' href='/'>ABOUT ME</A> 
            </li>
            <li>
            <A className='Link' href='/'>SKILLS</A> 
            </li>
            <li>
            <A className='Link' href='/'>PROJECTS</A> 
            </li>
            <li>
            <A className='Link' href='/'>BLOG</A> 
            </li>
            <li>
            <A className='Link' href='/'>CONTACT ME</A> 
            </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <div classname="changer">
            <MenuBookOutlined classname="menu"/>
        </div>

    </div>

    )
}

export default Header
```

```css
// Create the header and navbar styles
.header {
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.header_logo{
    margin-left: 4rem;
}

.navbar {
margin: 0 auto;
}

ul{
    display: flex;
    li{
        list-style: none;
        margin: 1rem;
    }

    a{
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: black;
    }
}

.changer{
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 1.5rem;
    
    .menu{
         cursor: pointer;
         margin-right: 1rem;
         display: none;
    }
}

.closed.close{
   display: none; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should only try changing `classname` into `className` (camelCase):

```js
<div className="changer">
    <MenuBookOutlined className="menu"/>
</div>
```

And we need to add an extra space between class names to make the close icon more specific (It has no space now)

```css
.closed .close {
  display: none;
}
```

I hope this helps.